# Not able to retrieve record from the Dyanmo DB in nest JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { DocumentClient } from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";

export class Service {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DYNAMODB_TOKEN) private readonly dynamodbClient: DocumentClient,
  ) {
    this.logger.setContext(Service.name);
  }


async findRecords(itemId: string): Promise<any> {    
    const method_name = "findRecordsById";
    this.logger.info(`Retrieving DlqRecords for the uuid: ${itemId}`);
    var output: any = "";
    try {
    var result = this.dynamodbClient.get({ TableName: this.DLQ_TABLE, Key: { id: itemId } }).promise();
    result.then(res=>{output=res.Item?res.Item:"not found"}).catch(err=>console.log(err));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        `Method Name: ${method_name} and UUID: ${itemId}: Find DLQ records failed with exception`
      );
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

I am not able to retrieve the record from Dyanmo DB in nest JS project. Tried below way to retrieve the records.
`aws-sdk dependency version : "^2.1282.0"`
`npm version: 8.19.1 node: v18.9.0`
Using getItem(). It did not gave any error however it didn't go neither inside if(err) nor else block and output was undefined.

Comment: Can you please describe your dynamo db table?

Answer (score 0):

You created a variable called `inputParams` but pass `params` to your API call `getItem(params)`. Try use `getItem(inputParams)`

If that fails try this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'}); 

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

   var inputParams = {
   TableName: this.DLQ_TABLE,
   Key: {
   "id" : {"S": itemId}
   }
   };

var result = await dynamodb.getItem(inputParams).promise()

result.then(res=>{output=res.Item?res.Item:"not found"}).catch(err=>console.log(err))

return output
```

### Edit Doc client example

```
import { DocumentClient } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb'
const ddb = new DocumentClient()
​
const TableName = this.DLQ_TABLE
const Key = {
   "id" :  itemId
   }
​
await ddb
  .get({
    TableName,
    Key,
  })
  .promise()
```

Comment: Thanks Lee. However upon trying the above code it is not executing any of the then or catch statement inside getItem() function.
var inputParams = {
        TableName: this.DLQ_TABLE,
        Key: {
        "id" : {"S": itemId}
        }
        };
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        dynamodb.getItem(inputParams).promise().then(res=>
          {this.logger.info(res);
          output = res.item;
          }
         ).catch(err=>{
          this.logger.error(err)
        })

Comment: Please edit your question and add more of your code. Where are you running it from?

Comment: I have edited the question with complete code. I am running it from Visual studio. It is a nest JS project. Running it standalone from the postman by exposing the service via controller.

Comment: You import JS SDK V3 initially `import { DocumentClient } from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";` but then proceed to import SDK V2 later, is there a reason? I'll also update my answer with more info based on your updated code.

Comment: Also, I think the response of dynamo is with a capital I (`Item` instead of `item`)

Comment: As mentioned, why dont you use the injected documentClient?, like `this.dynamodbClient.get({ TableName: DlqTable, Key: { id: itemId } })`

Comment: @AlejandroBarone : It is giving me runtime error ""trace":"this.dynamodbClient.get is not a function"}".

Comment: @LeeHannigan Sorry my bad. I removed the SDK V2 from the code and now its giving me this.dynamodbClient.get is not a function runtime error.

Comment: As you are using v2, the method should be `getItem` (with `Item` as the response), can you try that?

`const inputParams = { TableName: DlqTable, Key: { 'id': {S: itemId} };`
`var result = await dynamodb.getItem(inputParams).promise();`
`console.log(result.Item)`

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how I typically use tbe document client which is a little different than how you do it.

Comment: @AlejandroBarone I believe this was tried as I included it in my initial answer.

Comment: Thank you Guys for the responses. The issue was DocumentClient did not contain the credentials parameter set hence it was not able to authorize the permissions. Upon setting the creds it worked fine.

Comment: Like I mentioned, placing a try/catch around any API call will help you expose these errors and make the exceptions more clear. But I'm glad you got it fixed.